# Windows 7 Phone Application XML Reading

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

How to Read XML document in Windows 7 Phone application using C#

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself?  What are you trying to achieve with the xml?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working sample WP7 app reading XML using LINQ and databinding to a ListBox.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)